# How to add emotions in my chat window in php

Tags: php

Iam working on simple chat application,I want to add emotions(Smiley) on chat window.But i don't know how to do this,can anybody help me

like this

[image]
Thanks

Comment: [`preg_replace`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with an array of 'patterns' (ie the smiley faces you want to use) and the other with an array of `<img src="smile.png" />` to match the face you want.

Comment: You need to have conversion code that handles the :) being converted to an image output. This can be done via str_replace, preg_replace, or an array. Not really sure its our job to build your entire emoticon code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     function Smilify(&$subject)
     {
     $smilies = array(
    ':|'  => 'mellow',
    ':-|' => 'mellow',
    ':-o' => 'ohmy',
    ':-O' => 'ohmy',
    ':o'  => 'ohmy',
    ':O'  => 'ohmy',
    ';)'  => 'wink',
    ';-)' => 'wink',
    ':p'  => 'tongue',
    ':-p' => 'tongue',
    ':P'  => 'tongue',
    ':-P' => 'tongue',
    ':D'  => 'biggrin',
    ':-D' => 'biggrin',
    '8)'  => 'cool',
    '8-)' => 'cool',
    ':)'  => 'smile',
    ':-)' => 'smile',
    ':('  => 'sad',
    ':-(' => 'sad',
);

$sizes = array(
    'biggrin' => 18,
    'cool' => 20,
    'haha' => 20,
    'mellow' => 20,
    'ohmy' => 20,
    'sad' => 20,
    'smile' => 18,
    'tongue' => 20,
    'wink' => 20,
);

$replace = array();
foreach ($smilies as $smiley => $imgName)
{
    $size = $sizes[$imgName];
    array_push($replace, '<img src="imgs/'.$imgName.'.gif" alt="'.$smiley.'"  
     width="'.$size.'" height="'.$size.'" />');
}
$subject = str_replace(array_keys($smilies), $replace, $subject);
 }
```

Comment: I think that regex solution would be better because someone can enter not ":)" but ":))))"

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of codes  for smilies like ":-)" and have a conversion array such as.

```
$smile_keys = array(':-)',...,...etc)
$smile_images = array('face1.jpg',...,...etc);

echo str_replace($smile_keys, $smile_images, $text);
```

Thats one way of doing it that should look fairly simple.